# Export Google Bigquery "saved queries" when deleting project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

As the project where my  `SQL` "saved queries" is going to be deleted
my "saved queries" will also be deleted (so also the shared query url will be unuseful).
I could of course manually `copy/paste` all of them somewhere, but is there an automatic way to save all your "saved queries" statements for a project?
A solution connecting it to a `git` repo would be even better.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I dont think BigQuery exposes this as REST endpoint yet.
Here is the open feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111961970

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there's no availability to export your saved queries. Nevertheless, there's a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905756) to sync/export saved queries to Google Drive that may be help you.

You can [starring](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) the feature request as this will bring the BigQuery Engineering team's attention regarding this feature.

Hope it helps.